# how to get sharedpreference values on "Clear Data" from "Manage Application"

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am developing on app and in that app I store the values in the `SharedPreference`. I am able to store all the values successfully and also retrieving `SharedPreference` data. But when I clearing data from the `Manage Application` from `Settings` of device, it clears all these values. I have to perform several operations for the `SharedPreference` values when I am clearing data. Can I check this `clear data` event in my activity in android?

Comment: Then you have to use DATABASE for this , not sharedprefrence

Comment: can database erase values on `clear data`? because i want data to be erased on `clear data`

Comment: Not at all ............

Comment: have you tried for remove method in shared perference?

Comment: but how could i get to know user fired clear data from manage application in settings of device

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if user fired clear data from manage application in your activity in android check your SharedPreference if all the value you are looking for is empty for example

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
Log.i("Cointain Values" ,prefs.getAll().toString());
```